# How to calculate a new player winning probability with expert level player

Tags: statistics, data-science, probability

Let's say I have a online game where users can play each other. I have list of players, all players categorized as experts, average, below average. A new player wants to play this game, and the system choose expert level player against new player. what would be the winning probability of the new player?

ex: expert player data looks as:
total games: 45,
win: 30,
draw: 10,
loss: 5

Is it possible to do probability between new player vs expert player? If yes, what statistics can be considered?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would take a **subset of the data** which corresponds to **`expert` vs. `average` games**

- **If the expert in question has enough data** (do a [binomial test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html) to check if his win rate is statistically significant), then you can rely on his/her data alone. Eg If this particular expert has played 100 games against average players and won 80, that's significant, and you can say he/she has a 80% change of winning
- **If the expert doesn't have enough data** (ie to be significant), you can combine data from **ALL `expert` vs. `average` games** to compensate, although this raises another question: how did this player get awarded the expert rank if we believe there aren't enough games to determine this?

I believe the **main issue** here is that you **reduce all possible skill levels to 3** (expert vs. average vs. below average), whereas in reality there might be more granularity to how good or bad people are, thus your model might be over simplistic. **Introducing more levels would help address that issue** (eg 5 levels doesn't seem like too much for people to grasp and might already perform better than 3). Alternatively you can also try to **calculate probabilities based on more detailed properties** (eg win rate, # days user has been playing, age, gender...) even if it's something you only keep to yourself (ie players only see the `n` ranking levels but you have more detailed properties to do your calculations).